# C# - How to Both Await Tasks and Assign Values to Variables

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I've been attempting to figure this out for a bit now but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have the following async task which calls other async tasks from my ClientFunctions object named "c".

```
public async Task RunAsync(Dictionary<int, Robots> botList)
{
    this.botList = botList;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[botList.Count]; //5 tasks for each bot, 5 bots total in a list

    for (int i = 0; i < botList.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = botList[i].c.StartClient();
        await tasks[i];

        tasks[i] = botList[i].c.setConnection();
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Form1.Log("All done");
}
```

I await after `StartClient()` because it writes data to a shared file, and `setConnection()` reads the data from that file. I do this for all 5 bots.

The `StartClient()` function returns a Process, and I want to store that Process in each bot's class in a variable called "**proc**".

How would I go about storing the result while still being able to use a task array to wait for all 5 to complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation, assuming you want to `StartClient` on all bots sequentially and then call `setConnection` and `await` them all to finish.

```
public async Task RunAsync(Dictionary<int, Robots> botList)
{
    this.botList = botList;
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var botKvp in botList)
    {
        var bot = botKvp.Value;
        bot.proc = await bot.c.StartClient();
        tasks.Add(bot.c.setConnection());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Form1.Log("All done");            
}
```

`Task` comes in two varieties: `Task` and `Task<T>`. You have an array of `Task` which does not define a return value. If you want to return a value you need to `await` a `Task<T>`. For instance if `setConnection()` should return a `bool` then it's signature should declare that as `public Task<bool> setConnection(...)`

`Task[] tasks = new Task<Process>[botList.Count]`

should be

`Task<Process>[] tasks = new Task<Process>[botList.Count]`

This works

`bot.proc = await bot.c.StartClient();`

Becuase `StartClient()` returns `Task<Process>` and `await` awaits that task and assigns the process to `proc`. As counter example this will fail:

```
Task procTask = bot.c.StartClient();
bot.proc = await procTask
```

Comment: I guess this works in this context of starting the client synchronously and then asynchronously setting the connection, because `setConnection()` does not return a value, but how would it work if I wanted to return, say, a bool from setConnection as well?

My main problem is being able to not only wait for the task but also return a value from it at the same time.

Comment: I have the following for my `StartClient()` function:

`public async Task<Process> StartClient()
        {
            try
            {       
// stuff       
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
`

Comment: That's looks ok, but your putting the return of that into a `Task[]` it should be a `Task<Process>[]`

Comment: Putting the value into a `Task[]` removes that `Process` return value so you can access strictly by `await`

Comment: If I do `Task[] tasks = new Task<Process>[botList.Count]`, I get `co-variant array conversion from Task<Process>[] to Task[] can cause run-time exception on write operation`.

I can do `bot.proc = await bot.c.StartClient();` but I cannot do `bot.proc = await tasks[i];`

Comment: Updated to explain new comments

Answer (score 0):

When you await the task you get the result, so:

```
public async Task RunAsync(Dictionary<int, Robots> botList)
{
    this.botList = botList;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[botList.Count]; //5 tasks for each bot, 5 bots total in a list

    for (int i = 0; i < botList.Count; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = botList[i].c.StartClient();
        botList[i].proc = await tasks[i];

        tasks[i] = botList[i].c.setConnection();
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Form1.Log("All done");
}
```

If it were the `setConnection()` method that returned the item, the result of `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` would hold a collection of items.

Comment: @RonBeyer he is not awaiting the result of `setConnection` in for loop.

Comment: I used `Task.WhenAll` outside the for loop to wait for `setConnection()` to actually finish executing on all 5 bots before proceeding.

Comment: Isn't `Task.WhenAll` redundant here?

Comment: @PeteGO when doing `botList[i].proc = await tasks[i];` it gives me an error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Diagnostics.Process'`

Comment: `await tasks[i]` doesn't return a `Process` for `proc` it's a `Task`.

Comment: The op said: "The StartClient() function returns a Process"